# Combining tuple elements from a list of tuples. Tuple elements are tuple and list

Tags: python, list

I'm relatively new with Python and am having a hard time coming up with a way to make the following work.  Currently, I have a list of tuples (larger than `list_one`. The elements inside these tuples are 1) a tuple, and 2) a string (these strings are always one of two values: in the example `'A'` or `'B'` (can also be `'D'` or `'Z'`, or any other two strings). The inner tuples include an `'id'` and a `list` of values (strings):

```
list_one = [(('id1', ['v1', 'v2']), 'A'), (('id2', ['v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6']), 'A'), (('id3', ['v11']), 'B'), (('id4', ['v12', 'v13']), 'B'), (('id5', ['v14', 'v16']), 'B'), (('id6', ['v17', 'v18', 'v21']), 'A')]
```

I'm trying, unsuccessfully, to create a new list that looks as follows:

```
new_list1 = [('id1',['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6']), ('id3',['v11', 'v12', 'v13', 'v14', 'v16']), ('id6',['v17', 'v18', 'v21'])]
```

When the string value (A, B) changes it should create a new tuple with the first element being the id of the initial tuple where the A,B changes, and the second element being a list of the values ("v's") inside the initial lists. A list if dictionaries would also be fine, e.g:

```
new_list2 = [{'id1': ['v1','v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6']}, {'id3':['v11', 'v12', 'v13', 'v14', 'v16']}, {'id6':['v17', 'v18', 'v21']}]
```

I appreciate any guidance.

edit:

```
s = list_one[0][1]
for tup in list_one:
    if s in tup:
        new_list.extend(tup[0][1])
    else:
        new_list.append(tup[0][1])
```

gives:

```
 ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6', ['v11'], ['v12', 'v13'], ['v14', 'v16'], 'v17', 'v18', 'v21']
```

which is not really what I'm looking for, as this creates a list around one the 'A' value, with lists of 'B' inside.

Comment: Show us your code...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! State precisely: a) What you are tried so far (show a **Minimal Complete Verifiable Example**) b) Where are you getting stuck (again show code).

Comment: Ah, only just seen your comments. Thanks SuperSaiyan ;) To be honest I'm not sure at all about how to handle this particular problem. I've tried a number of things, see e.g. the edit in the main post. Doesn't seem like a very hard problem, but somehow can't come up with a nice way to approach 1) getting the adjacent "v's" that have the same 'id' in the same list, and then to create a new list with the "v's" of the second 'id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically loop along, remembering what is the current key (initialized to `None`).

```
key = None # This is 'A' or 'B' in your example, but it starts off as None
new_list = [] # This holds the final result
for r, l in [(r, l) for (l, r) in list_one]: 
    if r != key: # If the current is not the key, time to switch to a new one
        id_ = l[0]
        new_list.append({id_: []})
    new_list[-1][id_].extend(l[1]) # Extend the current list
    key = r # Make it the current key in any case.

>>> new_list
[{'id1': ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6']},
 {'id3': ['v11', 'v12', 'v13', 'v14', 'v16']},
 {'id6': ['v17', 'v18', 'v21']}]
```

Comment: id1 and id6 lists has the same letter A, so the lists belong together with the first id (id1) met in the tpl_list (as far as i understood). my out:
{'id3': ['v11', 'v12', 'v13', 'v14', 'v16'], 'id1': ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6', 'v17', 'v18', 'v21']}

Comment: @MiroRodozov Check out the explanation "When the string value (A, B) changes it should create a new tuple". Also, this exactly fits with the example the OP gave in the question. It doesn't look like yours does, though.

Comment: i see his desired result now, you are right fits exactly to the description given, anyway from what he said i understood the primary key should be the letter one, regardless in the final dict the first id to appear against that letter key has to be used. anyway, it was probably me to over engineered it

Comment: Thanks for both your responses. Ami understood my question correctly, Miro. That's probably my bad for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

This solves a related question, whereby all the lists corresponding to `'A'` and `'B'` values are aggregated, and the id is chose of the total first id for each group.

---

Here you go

```
letterKeyToFirstIDMap = {}
result_dict = {}

for tpl in list_one:

  id = tpl[0][0]
  lst = tpl[0][1]
  letter_id = tpl[1]
  if not letter_id in letterKeyToFirstIDMap: 
    letterKeyToFirstIDMap.update({letter_id: id})
    result_dict.update({id:[]})

  result_dict[letterKeyToFirstIDMap[letter_id]] += lst

print result_dict
```

What is done here is that for each letter key (say A) you want only the first id that is met (say id1) to be the key for the following list. You create a map to store the letterKey and its idKey the first time the pair appears and then just check if the letter key already exists in that map, using it's corresponding idKey if it does, and update the list.

Comment: Check out the example output below "I'm trying, unsuccessfully, to create a new list that looks as follows:" in the question. I'm not sure yours outputs it (it seems to combine everything to two lists in that case).

Comment: I'm upvoting this, as the question was a bit hard to follow, and it solved a related question.